# Database design help needed

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am a large social networking site, say mynetwork.com. It will have a lot of features like albums, forums, jobs board and so on (Php + MySQL + Yii)

Now, the users of this site will be able to create networks for their own community which can be accessed by community-1.mynetwork.com or community-2.mynetwork.com etc.

So, I am not sure whats the best way to design the database. One way, I can come up with is to have a unique Id for each network and have a network_Id field in each table.

Is there any better way?

Comment: Are the different communities private (i.e. separate from each other) or do they interact? After all, each community could have their own copy of the database…

Comment: @Tomalak: There would still probably be some shared reference data so that would be best located in some sort of shared schema.

Comment: Each community is separate from the other. However, having a different copy of database, will make maintenance and changes difficult, wont it?

Comment: But in this case, *not* having separate databases is a security risk. ;-)

Comment: Tomalak: I think in this case, you both might be right. ;)

Answer (score 1):

> One way, I can come up with is to have
>   a unique Id for each network and have
>   a network_Id field in each table.

Isn't `community-1.mynetwork.com` already unique?

The process for developing a logical data model is the same whether you're designing a large social networking site or an accounting application, isn't it?

"Have a network_Id field in each table" is an idea. It isn't a design.